# GEE - Confused about error matrix parameters

Tags: google-earth-engine

I tried to calculating the error matrix for my classifications map.
I am confused about error matrix parameters.

I split my samples into 2 categories, 70% for training and 30% for validation.

Example code:
`var validation = validSample.errorMatrix('q1','q2')`

Which parameters do I need to use for `q1`?

The **feature collections** (30% sample)? **or** **classified image** using 30% sample? I mean, do I have to make a new classification image using 30% sample?

`q2`: classified image using **training** sample.

Answer (score 0):

As the errorMatrix function says:: errorMatrix(actual, predicted).
So q1 is the feature collections (30% sample).

One way to do classification and accuracy assessment is::

```
//suppose Train is 70% of the original dataset and Test is 30% of it.
// and Image is our satellite image
var Data = Image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: Train, 
  properties: ['Class'], 
  scale: 10
});

var classifier1 = ee.Classifier.libsvm({kernelType: 'RBF',gamma: 2,cost: 10})
  .train({
  features: Data, 
  classProperty: 'Class', 
  inputProperties: bands,
});

var classified = Image.classify(classifier1);

var validData = classified.sampleRegions({
  collection: Test, 
  properties: ['Class'], 
  scale: 10
});

var errorMatrix1 = validData.errorMatrix('Class', 'classification');
```

Hope it helps.